# Pandas: Removing duplicate rows in a Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 tables with 3 rows and 3 columns:

```
   Table 1                                 Table 2
 1   7    9                              1    4   7
 2   4   11                             12   -4  -1
 7   3    2                              2    4   11
```

I want to merge these two tables into one data frame and remove duplicate rows:

```
Expected Output (Table 3):
1    7   9
7    3   2
1    4   7
12  -4  -1
```

I also want the output to be in excel. **What is wrong with my code below?**:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np

 df1 = pd.read_excel('Table 1.xlsx')
 df2 = pd.read_excel('Table 2.xlsx')

 frames = [df1,df2]
 result = pd.concat(frames)

 no_duplicates = result.drop_duplicates(False)

 import xlsxwriter
 workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Table 3.xlsx', {'constant_memory': True})
 worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
 row = 0

for row, group in enumerate (no_duplicates):
 for col in range(3):
    worksheet.write (row, col, group[col])

workbook.close()
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having? Are you getting an error? Is the output wrong? If so, what's wrong with it?

Comment: `no_duplicates.to_excel('Table 3.xlsx', index=False)` is easier to use to save output dataframe to excel instead of `xlsxwriter`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your dropping duplicate code.  Can you clarify what you're actual problem is?

Comment: When I tried it with large file sizes, it just did not work. I exceeded the maximum rows in the excel sheet. Any ideas on how to continue printing on Sheet 2 after Sheet 1 is maxed out?

Comment: @user7970547 pandas can not do anything about limitation of excel , maybe just try csv .

Comment: you could save it as a `.csv` instead since you are exceeding the spreadsheet row limit.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
df1=pd.DataFrame([[1,7,9],[2,4,11],[7,3,2]])
df2=pd.DataFrame([[1,4,7],[12,-4,-1],[2,4,11]])
df=pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
wr = ExcelWriter('./sample.xlsx')
df.to_excel(wr,'Sheet5',index=False)
wr.save()
```